# How to create programmatically a new Site and assign to it some groups

Tags: site-template, groups, site

I'm creating a web service to "connect" a my app to Sharepoint.. I want to expose a method to programmatically create a web site: imagine to have in input things like "name", "description", "url" and so on...

I tried this way: (Obv this is a "static" version in which parameters are constants, next step is to pass him the values in the AddGroup Obj)

```
 [WebMethod]
    public ResponseObject addGroup()//AddGroup addGroupObj)
    {

        try
        {
            string fullsite = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/sites/Reply Corp";

            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                            {
                                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(fullsite))
                                {
                                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                    site.AllWebs.Add("RELATIVE", "TITOLO", "DESCRIZIONE", 1033, "Sfera", false, false); //1033 = English

                                    //How to mess up with groups?
                                }
                            });
            return new ResponseObject() { SPResultStatus = ResponseObjectSPResultStatus.SUCCESS };
        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            return new ResponseObject() { Message = exx.Message, ExceptionType = exx.GetType().ToString(), Stacktrace =exx.StackTrace, SPResultStatus = ResponseObjectSPResultStatus.FAILURE,  };
        }

    }
```

What i'm doing wrong?

The "Sfera" is a Custom Template which exists on the site..

The exception I'm getting now is:

File or arguments not valid for site template 'Sfera'.

There is another way to assign a custom template?? Thank you very much!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "The language is not supported on the server."

Answer (score 3):

The LCID number is wrong (the fourth parameter), it should be one of this list instead than 123:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/goglobal/bb964664.aspx

The US-English is 1033.

Remember also that if you try to create sites with a non administrator user you should use RunWithElevatedPrivileges method.